# SOAPUI - Excel file is locked thought excel process of the instance running not found in tasklist in cmd

Tags: excel, groovy, soapui

[image: excelscreen]

I am using soapui along with groovy to read some data in excel. unable to open the excel after running to the script to read data. 
workbook.close() isn't helping. 
i need to close the soapui instance to re-open the excel file. 
what can i do to release the excel instance without terminating soapui instance?

```
def ExcelInstance(String testdatapath,String Sheetname) {
    try {
        wb = WorkbookFactory(new File(testdatapath));
        this.sheetname=Sheetname;
        for(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet: wb) {
            if(Sheetname==sheet.getSheetName())
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("Exception: ${e}" )
    }
}

def releaseExcel(){
    wb.close() wb.quit()
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Apache POI. Are you using a FileOutputStream and if so, do you close it at the end?

Comment: Yes i am using apache POI. No i am not using FileOutputStream as i just need to read excel data. below is the cope snippet.

Comment: def ExcelInstance(String testdatapath,String Sheetname)   {
  try{
  wb = WorkbookFactory(new File(testdatapath));  

     this.sheetname=Sheetname;
      for(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet: wb) {
    
    if(Sheetname==sheet.getSheetName())
   break;
    } 
    
     }
   catch (Exception e) {
    log.info("Exception: ${e}"  )
      }
}

def releaseExcel(){

 wb.close()
     wb.quit()
 }

Answer (score 0):

Off hand I would say you don't pass the wb object to releaseExcel().

Where you make the call to releaseExcel(), pass the wb object. That means the calling code needs visibility of it. So the code that instantiates the wb object needs to return the object to the controlling code, and then it can be passed as

```
releaseExcel(wb)
```

Comment: wb instance is currently in the same class and accessible by releaseExcel() method. did try releaseExcel(wb) as well, but the excel still appears locked